# Access parent data inside cellTemplate devextreme angular

Tags: angular, devextreme, devextreme-angular

How do I access   weekday   from inside the   dxTemplate   below?

```
<dxi-column *ngFor="let weekday of calendarWeek" alignment="center" caption="{{weekday.Day}}">
    <dxi-column alignment="center" caption="{{weekday.Date}}">
        <dxi-column caption="7 8 9 10 11 12 1 2 3 4 5 6 7" [width]="182" cellTemplate="chartCellTemplate"></dxi-column>
    </dxi-column>
</dxi-column>
```

so weekday above needs to be accessed in the  below to compare against  schedule

```
<div *dxTemplate="let instructor of 'chartCellTemplate'">
    <div class="chart-cell">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding:0px; border:0; margin: 0px;">
                    <div *ngFor="let schedule of instructor.data.ScheduleDisplay" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': schedule.activityColor, 'color': schedule.activityColor, width:schedule.activityLength, padding:'0px', border:'0px', margin:'0px', display:'inline-block'}">{{weekday.data.Date}}</div>
                </td>                
            </tr>                    
        </table>               
    </div>
</div>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-devextreme-sandbox-eycsyy

Answer (score 0):

According to the [cellTemplate](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Configuration/columns/#cellTemplate) API reference, the **data** parameter contains information about row data. So you need to use `instructor.data` instead of the `weekday.data` definition.

Comment: I have tried that, but there is no value for Date in there... 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-devextreme-sandbox-eycsyy